# How to shorten QString in a way, that when converted to UTF-8 it is shorter than certain length?

Tags: utf-8, qstring

I am trying to create an efficient algorithm, for shortening QString, so when converted to UTF-8 it would be shorter than defined length and still be valid UTF-8.

- Input

  - QString text - string with all possible characters - no maximal length specified
  - int limit - the maximal length of the output encoded in utf-8
- Output

  - QByteArray output - the original text in utf-8 shorter than limit.
- example1:

  - text = "How are you?"
  - limit = 5
  - output = "How a"
- example2:

  - text = "Как дела?"
  - limit = 5
  - output = "Ка"

    - d0 9a d0 b0 - including "к" would be already over the limit and including d0 would result in not valid utf-8 string.

First we started with the following code, but that may cut the UTF-8 character in the middle, which is not acceptable:

```
QByteArray output = text.toUtf8().left(limit);
```

Than we developed correct algorithm which works, but is quite ugly and not efficient:

```
QString tmp = input;
while (tmp.toUtf8().size() > limit)
    tmp.chop(1);
QByteArray output = tmp.toUtf8();
```

- Is there a better method, how to do this?

  - If yes, please share the code?
  - If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach should be optimal unless you want to write your own UTF-8 conversion routine. It relies on the fact that continuation bytes in UTF-8 sequences are in the range 0x80-0xBF. Going backward from the limit, it tries to find the first starting byte at which the string can be split safely.

```cpp
QByteArray output = tmp.toUtf8();
if (output.size() > limit) {
    int truncateAt = 0;
    for (int i = limit; i > 0; i--) {
        if ((output[i] & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
            truncateAt = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    output.truncate(truncateAt);
}
```

Since UTF-8 byte sequences aren't longer than 4 bytes, it shouldn't take more than 4 loop iterations to find the correct position.

Comment: Are you sure about your assumption: "all UTF-8 characters start with a byte in the 0-127 range". According to http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024 all Russian characters starts with 0xd0, so for the "Как дела?" and 5 your algorithm would returned empty string.

Comment: @RadekDostal Sorry, that was wrong. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for info. It's a pity that there is no direct qt function for this.